# What happens to the values of object in windows phone 8 navigation?

Tags: windows-phone-8

When navigating for one page to another does the value of the objects in the previous pages get lost? As I am navigating from `page-1` to `page-2` and then in `page-2` I am calling a method which is in `page-1` the values returned are null.

Why is this happening?

first page:

```
public Offer qw()
{
    return off;
} 
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml" ,UriKind.Relative));
```

page2:

```
var ob=obj.qw();
values in ob=null
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating your `obj` field in your page2 means you are creating a new instance of the page1 so obviously it will differ from previous page.

so if you want to execute thi sfunctionality in page behind means you can do this in your page2

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{

  // NavigationEventArgs returns destination page
  Page destinationPage = e.Content as Page2;
  if (destinationPage != null) 
    {

        // Change property of destination page
        destinationPage.Page1=this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bad logic for Windows Phone application. If you need to send some object from **Page_1** to **Page_N** you should use **PhoneApplicationService**, if you send some simple object-type (numbers, strings, bools) you can use **NavigationContext**.

**Sample PhoneApplicationService:**

```
   // Page_1 before navigate to Page_N
   PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[key] = value; // key(string); value(any object)

   // Page_N
   object o;
   PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.TryGetValue(key, out o)
   // then do what you want with you object - o
```

**Sample NavigationContext:**

```
   // Page_1 before navigate to Page_N
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=SomeMessageText", UriKind.Relative));

   // Page_N
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            string msg = "";

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))

                string yourMessage = msg;


        }
```

See MSDN:

- [NavigationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx)
- [PhoneApplicationService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice(v=vs.105).aspx) and [PhoneApplicationService samples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/724883/How-to-Pass-Values-Between-Pages-in-Windows-Phone)